# Maintaining Bluetooth Low Energy Connection Even when changing activities

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I want to have an Activity A where you create a BLE connection with a BLE device. After doing so, it will take you to a new activity B to display the data received by the BLE device. From research I've noticed people mentioning that the BLE connection might be lost when changing activities. I was wondering what advice you would give for maintaining that BLE connection even when switching activities. I'm currently using a service named UARTService to handle the BLE connection and I've read using a Service could make it possible to due what I desire.

Please advise

Comment: You do not need a `Service` necessarily. You probably do want to have some singleton manager of your BLE connection.

Comment: How would I implement this singleton manager, if for example, I have a Service for BLE connection?

Comment: Ideally, you would use a dependency inversion framework (Dagger, Koin, etc.). Otherwise, in Kotlin, you could just use a top-level `object`. In Java, there are plenty of examples of patterns for creating singletons, such as the ones covered in [this blog post](https://www.baeldung.com/java-singleton).